# VIM Omnicomplete causing error with youcompleteme plugin

Tags: vim, omnicomplete, youcompleteme

I have an issue with vim completion in a javascript file.

Any character after the period '.' character as in the line below

```
this.*
```

produces an error:

```
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Complete..<SNR>78_GetCompletions:
line    1:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

The omnicomplete function for js files is:

```
javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
```

My vim build details are:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 25 2014 11:27:58)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-430
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         -gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o vim        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python   -lruby.2.0.0 -lobjc
```

Comment: YouCompleteMe has a dedicated issue tracker.

Comment: I'm aware of this. The issue however does not appear to be an issue with youcomplete but rather the input to it from omnicomplete. E.g see: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/958

Comment: If you get some error with `<C-x><C-o>` (no completion, error messages…), the completion function is to blame. If you don't, YouCompleteMe is to blame.

Comment: I don't get any errors with the initial completion options. The completion window displays fine.  As soon as I enter any character after period, or if i have chosen a completion and then enter another character, it bails out with the error listed above.

Comment: So the issue occurs when refining the list of completions or adding a character immediately after a selected completion.

Comment: I wont repeat it again: try with `<C-x><C-o>`, not with YCM.